# What did George Boole contribute to order theory?

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-logic

The Wikipedia page says for [order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#History) says:

> As explained before, orders are ubiquitous in mathematics. However, earliest explicit mentionings of partial orders are probably to be found not before the 19th century. In this context the works of George Boole are of great importance.

The page on [George Boole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole) doesn't mention order, beyond the idea of "orders of logic" (especially first-order logic). Is this Boole's contribution to order theory? Or is there some other contribution of Boole?

Comment: Maybe Schroder's *Vorlesungen iiber die Algebra
der Logik* (1890, 1891) where the [*subsumption*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2271822) relation is introduced, whose primary interpretation is that of inclusion, that has the two general properties of reflexivity and transitivity and thus the properties of a *partial order*.

Comment: What we call today a boolean algebra emerged later from Boole's work; see e.g. Edward Huntington, [Sets of Independent Postulates for the Algebra of Logic (1904)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1986459#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: And see Edward Huntington, [The continuum and other types of serial order: With an introduction to Cantor's transfinite numbers (1917, 1st ed.1905)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Continuum_and_Other_Types_of_Serial/pPjDD5QnRd4C), **Ch.2 General properties of Simply Ordered Classes of Series**, page 10.

Comment: See also: Stephen Pollard (editor) [Ernst Schröder on Algebra and Logic (Springer, 2022)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Ernst_Schr%C3%B6der_on_Algebra_and_Logic/Hxx-EAAAQBAJ).